# Load multiple models(aggregation) in forge viewer and load other models as hidden by default until user selects from model browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load multiple models(aggregation) on to the forge viewer(v.6.x) initially while loading, but I want to show only one model and other models as hidden by default(can be with ghost view). Later when user clicks on eye icon from model browser, then that model should be visible/hidden.

I tried calling viewer.hideModel(modelId) after loading the model. But even though the model is showing in model browser, when I click on it, it says error model is not loaded.

```
var showModel = false;
this.viewer.loadModel(url, {globalOffset: { x:0, y:0, z:0 }, modelNameOverride: modelName}, () => 
  {
    this.isModelLoaded = true;
    this.viewer.caller = this;
    this.addEventListenersToViewer();
    if(!showModel){
      this.viewer.hideModel(modelId); // This is to hide the model by default after loading.
    }
  },
errorMsg => {
  this.isModelLoaded = false;
  this.viewer.container.style.opacity = 0;
  this.modelLoadError(this.fetchTranslationByKey('getModelError'));
  }
);
```

Expected behavior is to allow user to select from model browser, which models to show/hide on the viewer among all the models loaded initially(linked models should be hidden by default).

Current result I am getting is the linked models are showing in the model browser but when I click on that it says - Error Model is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here:

- When using arrow function the context that `this` points to is different so be careful with that
- how did you obtain the `modelId`? Instead of using arbitrary counter better to iterate the model array via `Viewer.impl.modelQueue()`
- I am unable to replicate the model not loaded error with model browser. Can you provide more details or a live sample (jsfiddle/jsbin)?